# on the interior of $F_\sigma$ sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $F$ be an $F_\sigma$ set of $X$ such tat its closure has not empty interior. Is true that also $F$ has not empty interior? I tried with the known fact that the interior is the complement of the closure of the coplement, but without success. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: Take $F=\Bbb Q$ in the space $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology.